# One OnClickListener for multiple dynamically generated button in OnSuccess of AsyncHttpClient

Tags: android, view, onclicklistener, asynchttpclient

I am facing problem while implementig one `OnClickListener` for multiple buttons. These buttons are dynamically generated based on the response in the OnSuccess of `AsyncHttpClient`.

If I am writing `OnClickListener` for each button, everything is working. But when I implements `OnClickListener`  and Override the `onClick(View v)` and calling `b1.setOnClickListener(this);` inside OnSuccess  (of AsyncHttpClient), I am getting error - ***The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){})***

Below is my code structure

```
public class USFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {



public void getUSData(String loc, String bc, String bm){

AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get("url",reqparams ,new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {


    public void onSuccess(String response) {

    //getting arraylist from jason response     
    if(count == 2)
    {
        Button b1 = new Button(getActivity());
        b1.setText("Click for Suc Uplds");  
        b1.setId(count);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);  //getting error here 
        // below commented code works, but i dont want to write onclickListener for each button.
        /*b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), UploadOnClickDetailsActivity.class);

                                            myIntent.putExtra("detailType", v.getId()  );

                                            startActivity(myIntent);
                                        }
                                    });*/

     tr1.addView(b1);

    }                               
    }

}



}



 @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
//depend on button id or v.getId, I am starting another activity

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), UploadOnClickDetailsActivity.class);

        myIntent.putExtra("detailType", v.getId()  );

        startActivity(myIntent);
}


}
```

Your help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: use  b1.setOnClickListener(USFragment.this);

Comment: Sanjay Kumar is right, but a little explanation might be nice. `this` points to the object you're currently working in. Because you're setting the listener in the anonymous class of `AsyncHttpResponseHandler`, `this` points to the instance of that class rather than to your `USFragment`

Comment: @SanjayKumar ..thanks its working..!! This should be the answer.